# Viewing array of pointers to structures in Visual Studio in the debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm having a problem displaying the contents of a pointer array with its contents in the debugger. If I just add the pointer to the watch only the fist entry is visible. But if I add the length to it the debugger assumes that I have something like `array[length][length]`.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Uyd.png)  [image: VS debugger]

The first entry is the broken one, looks the same with `,2` or with any `,2 x`. The second one is what I would like to see, but for more entries.

*Edit:* The two entries displayed as `[x][1]` are invalid.

I'm using VS 2005 but I think I had this problem on 2008 as well.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's really hard to read that picture.  Can you post the actual expressions you are evaluating?

Comment: I added a direct link to the picture above it - I have this problem with any struct Foo ** pointer.